# Is there a maximum size for Riak sets?

Tags: performance, riak

Is there a maximum size for [Riak sets](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/data-types/sets/) or some significant performance degradation at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Riak 2.0.x the recommended max size of a CRDT map/set stood at 100-200 KB of raw data (keys and values). The performance of Riak data types has been being constantly improved, but there is still a practical limit. The best way to determine what size works for your application is benchmarking your specific use-cases.

See [Guidance notes for CRDT performance issues](https://gist.github.com/lenary/8812739) and [Benchmarking large Riak data types](http://kyle.marek-spartz.org/posts/2014-12-03-benchmarking-large-riak-data-types-a-potential-fix.html), for example.

Keep in mind that as a rule of thumb Basho recommends keeping the size of stored objects under 100 KB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vempo. I think there is a performance impact even within that range with tiny elements, but I should benchmark to confirm that assumption.